# LARAGON img path

Tags: php, localhost, laragon

I added an image file on my project folder in laragon root with the following path:

C:\laragon\www\myproject\public\img\image.jpg
and another on
C:\laragon\www\myproject\resources\img\image.jpg

when previewing the project using Docker Desktop, the url is http://localhost/myproject but can't seem to display my image on the page.

What should be the correct path to access my images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asset` function:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/image.jpg') }}" alt="My Image">
```